# ReactJs how to hide load more option after all data fetch from database?

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand how to hide load more option when all of the list has been fetched from the database. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            limit: 5,
            isLoading:false
        }
    },

    onLoadMore() {
        this.setState({
            limit: this.state.limit + 5
        });
    },

    renderTodos: function(){
        var {todos} = this.props;
        return todos.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((todo)=>{
            return(
                    <Todo key={todo.todo_id}{...todo} onToggle={this.props.onToggle} editTask={this.props.editTask}/>
            );
        });
    },

    render:function(){
        var {todos} = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderTodos()}
                <br/>
               {todos.length>5 ?<a className="button" onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load More</a>:null }
            </div>
        )
    }
});
module.exports=TodoList;
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors? You're using class syntax with that `onLoadMore()` instead of regular prototype-based inheritance. What happens if you change `onLoadMore()` to `onLoadMore: function ()`?

Comment: Also you're checking the length of a `prop` that component is receiving from a parent. Are you sure these props are going through okay? Try logging them in `render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this condition on button:

```
this.state.limit < this.props.todos.length
```

This means that whenever the `state limit` value exceeds the total `todos array` length, remove the load more button.

Like this:

```
{
    todos.length > 5 && this.state.limit < this.props.todos.length ?  
        <a
            className="button" 
            onClick={this.onLoadMore}
        >
            Load More
        </a>
    :null 
}
```